# How to turn the global gps on from react native?

Tags: react-native, geolocation, android-permissions

Currently I am able to access the location of the user when the user give permission for the location and if the the gps is turned on. But if the user turned off the gps, I am not able to access the location. In that case how to ask the user to turn on that from react native itself?

This is my current logic. But this will fail to access the location if the user turned off the gps. How to ask the user to turn it on in a click of a button or something?

```
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {PermissionsAndroid} from 'react-native';
import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation';

const useUserLocation = () => {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);
  const [locationError, setLocationError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchLocation = async () => {
      try {
        const granted = await requestLocationPermission();
        if (granted) {
          Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            position => {
              const {latitude, longitude} = position.coords;
              setLocation({latitude, longitude});
            },
            error => {
              setLocationError(error.message);
            },
            {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000},
          );
        } else {
          setLocationError('Location permission denied');
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.warn(err);
        setLocationError('Error getting location');
      }
    };

    fetchLocation();

    return () => {
      Geolocation.clearWatch();
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (locationError) {
      console.log('location error : ', locationError);
    }
  }, [locationError]);

  const requestLocationPermission = async () => {
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        {
          title: 'Location Permission',
          message:
            'This app needs access to your location to show your current position.',
          buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
          buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
          buttonPositive: 'OK',
        },
      );
      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        console.log('Location permission granted');
        return true;
      } else {
        console.log('Location permission denied');
        return false;
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err);
      return false;
    }
  };

  return {location, locationError};
};

export default useUserLocation;
```

Comment: If no permission granted, prompt alert then call Linking.openSettigs() tell user to enable it.